# Why would you convert a JSON file to XML and vice versa?

Tags: xml, json, web-services, parsing

I know that both of them are similar in the sense that they both help in creating web services. I have found many sites/ tools that are used to convert a JSON to XML and vice versa. My question is why is it necessary. Both have their independent parser. Both when used give similar performance. Even if we assume that JSON is more efficient than XML, converting XML to JSON would also consume resources and vice versa. 
So why would you convert them? If you don't have a certain parser than add them. It is fairly simple and would be better than converting externally.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are all sorts of plausible reasons, but I think the most compelling one would be something like this:  Assume you've got a file in one format that needs to be loaded into a program that only supports the other.  Which is easier: Running the file through a conversion utility? Or developing, testing, and deploying a whole new version of your application that adds support for the other format?

In a big project, one option could take only a minute while the other might require days or weeks of effort once you factor in all the business processes that might have to come into play.

Comment: Aren't there completely developed and tested open source XML and JSON parsers for almost any platform?

Comment: @NilayVishwakarma Yes, but even with an off-the-shelf solution (which you should almost always be opting for, anyway) it still takes effort to do the integration.  Also note that my time estimate was assuming you've got a fairly simple app where the data's only being touched on one layer.  If it's being touched by many components, then the cost of adding support for an additional format to all those components could be vastly greater.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above the primary use is for web services. Some are developed to use XML and others JSON, thus if you get data from one service in XML and need to submit it to another service in JSON format you will need to convert it. both XML and JSON have their up sides and down sides. There are as many reasons to convert between the two as there are uses of the two.

We must also keep in mind that although web services implement these formats interchangeably they were developed for different reasons. XML is a mark up language at heart, although it is often used to represent data it can also be used to represent a document and its associated formatting or styles. JSON is at heart a simple serialization of an object hence JavaScript Object Notation.

Answer (score 0):

Not all Web Services and their corresponding client applications are developed by the same People. Some users of the web service might prefer xml while others look for JSON.

- Also, JSON will have a lower overhead on the amount of data required
  to be transferred.
- While XML can be more verbose and can be easier to    parse without
  documentation.

Comment: But what about performance issues, aren't they nothing but the most important issue in application lifecycle?

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as asking why we convert XML to Java objects, or JSON data to SQL data, or anything else: if we can't build our systems using a single technology end to end, we have to do conversions. Of course, using one technology end-to-end is always better; hence the advocates of XRX architecture in which the data is in XML format throughout the whole system. But in practice, systems are built from heterogeneous components developed by different people at different times, and data has to be converted at the boundaries between components.